# Cross GSuite Organizations Domain-Wide Delegation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-workspace, google-directory-api

Consider this scenario:

I have two domains:  `domain1.net` and `domain2.net`.

I have GCP enabled on `domain1.net` and created a Service Account here that has Domain-Wide Delegation Enabled.

The `CLIENT ID` from this Service Account is configured on `domain1.net` GSuite Admin Console as domain wide delegation and has the following `OAuth2` scopes enabled:

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly',
]
```

I have a `Cloud Function` that uses the Service Account's rights to create a `OAuth2 JWT`, to be able to  access GSuite `domain1.net` APIs. [Code Sample Here.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object)

The user to impersonate in GSuite has Group Admin Roles to be able to create GSuite Groups.

All this configuration works perfectly, I am able to create Groups in `domain1.net` using a Cloud Funtion in `domain1.net` GCP env.

But if I use the same Service Account `CLIENT ID` in `domain2.net` give the same `OAuth2` Scopes, create an user with Group Admin Roles and use this user to create new groups, it doesn't work.

Error:

```
error got with oauth2client==4.1.3
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.

error got with google.oauth2:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.
```

Now the above error code: `unauthorized_client` found in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#error-codes) specifies that the `CLIENT ID` is incorrect and I've might have used the Service Account's email, which I did not.

**Is Domain-Wide Delegation cross GSuite organization(different domain) capable?**
I know that it works in any sub-domain of `domain1.net` but not in any other GSuite organization(different domain like `domain2.net`).

Answer (score 1):

I have good news for you  (This won't answer your question but **will solve** your problem)!

You won't need to impersonate an admin anymore to create groups. Google just last week announced that the Cloud Identity Groups API will now allow for Group Management via API w/o impersonating an admin.

Take a look at these update blogs:

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/use-service-accounts-google-groups-without-domain-wide-delegation.html

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/service-accounts-in-google-groups-beta.html

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/new-api-cloud-identity-groups-google.html

I can't help you with the actual question, tho; that's just not my territory.

Answer (score 0):

A service account belongs to the application for which you created it. If this application belongs to `domain1.net`, the service account will be able to impersonate accounts from `domain1.net`, not from any other domain.

If you want a service account to impersonate users from `domain2.net`, create another service account on a GCP project that belongs to `domain2.net`.

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)